# Oracle SQL: Transpose Multiple Columns to Row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Best method used in Transposing Multiple columns to rows

Given:

```
            A    B  C   D   E   F   G 
    FYQ1    11  10  8   6   1   0   0
    FYQ2    11  10  8   7   2   0   0
    FYQ3    11  11  11  10  5   4   0
    FYQ4    11  11  11  10  5   4   0
```

Required:

```
        FYQ1 FYQ2 FYQ3 FYQ4
    A   11   11     11  11
    B   10   10     11  11
    C   8    8      11  11
    D   6    7      10  10
    E   1    2      5   5
    F   0    0      4   4
    G   0    0      0   0
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an aggregation function?  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: 12c, can we do it using aggregation ??,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you edit your question.

You can try to use condition aggregate function  with `UNION ALL`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Name varchar(50),
   A int,
   B int,
   C int,
   D int,
   E int,
   F int,
   G int
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ1',11,10,8 ,6,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ2',11,10,8 ,7,2,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ3',11,11,11,10,5,4,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ4',11,11,11,10,5,4,0);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 'A' as " ",
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ1' THEN A END) FYQ1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ2' THEN A END) FYQ2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ3' THEN A END) FYQ3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ4' THEN A END) FYQ4
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ1' THEN C END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ2' THEN C END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ3' THEN C END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ4' THEN C END)
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ1' THEN D END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ2' THEN D END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ3' THEN D END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ4' THEN D END)
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E',
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ1' THEN E END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ2' THEN E END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ3' THEN E END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ4' THEN E END)
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F',
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ1' THEN F END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ2' THEN F END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ3' THEN F END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ4' THEN F END)
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'G',
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ1' THEN G END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ2' THEN G END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ3' THEN G END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN  NAME = 'FYQ4' THEN G END)
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fafd78/16/0)**:

```
|   | FYQ1 | FYQ2 | FYQ3 | FYQ4 |
|---|------|------|------|------|
| A |   11 |   11 |   11 |   11 |
| C |    8 |    8 |   11 |   11 |
| D |    6 |    7 |   10 |   10 |
| E |    1 |    2 |    5 |    5 |
| F |    0 |    0 |    4 |    4 |
| G |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

Comment: Can we optimize this using WITH Clause?? By Just doing all the T table computation once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpivot and pivot, i share example.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Name varchar(50),
   A int,
   B int,
   C int,
   D int,
   E int,
   F int,
   G int
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ1',11,10,8 ,6,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ2',11,10,8 ,7,2,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ3',11,11,11,10,5,4,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('FYQ4',11,11,11,10,5,4,0);

SELECT   words,
         fyq1,
         fyq2,
         fyq3,
         fyq4
FROM     (
                SELECT name,
                       fyq1 AS words,
                       value
                FROM   (
                              SELECT                                                 *
                              FROM   t) unpivot ( (value) FOR (fyq1,fyq2,fyq3,fyq4) IN (a,
                                                                                        b,
                                                                                        c,
                                                                                        d,
                                                                                        e,
                                                                                        f,
                                                                                        g) )) pivot( SUM(value) FOR name IN ('FYQ1' AS fyq1,
                                                                                                                             'FYQ2' AS fyq2,
                                                                                                                             'FYQ3' AS fyq3,
                                                                                                                             'FYQ4' AS fyq4) )
ORDER BY words;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).